# Comparing 2 arrays fast in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, sorting, multidimensional-array

So there are 2 csv files that i read , with around 25k records. One is Old CSV and one is New CSV.  I need to compare if 'primary_contact' field is different in the new CSV file as compared to the old CSV record, while the 'name' , 'state' and 'city' fields are same in both old and new CSV.

**New CSV :**

```
Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => ID
        [1] => NAME
        [2] => STATE
        [3] => CITY
        [4] => COUNTY
        [5] => ADDRESS
        [6] => PHONE
        [7] => PRIMARY CONTACT
        [8] => POSITION
        [9] => EMAIL
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2002
        [1] => Abbeville Christian Academy
        [2] => Alabama
        [3] => Abbeville
        [4] => Henry
        [5] => Po Box 9 Abbeville, AL 36310-0009
        [6] => (334) 585-5100
        [7] => Ashley Carlisle
        [8] => Athletic Director
        [9] => acarlisle@acagenerals.org
    )

}
```

The issue is that i did 2 foreach nested loops to compare and it was fine for smal records , but when i ran Old and New CSV files containing 25k records each, the process took forever to complete.

There are some **duplicates** in both CSVs , so i remove them first ;

```
function multi_unique($data){
    $data = array_reverse($data);

    $result = array_reverse( // Reverse array to the initial order.
        array_values( // Get rid of string keys (make array indexed again).
            array_combine( // Create array taking keys from column and values from the base array.
                array_column($data, 1), 
                $data
            )
        )
    );

    return $result;
}

$old_csv=multi_unique($old_csv);
$new_csv=multi_unique($new_csv);
```

Here is **my comparison code, i need something faster** than this;

```
$name_index_no = 1;
$state_index_no = 2;
$city_index_no = 3;
$country_index_no = 4;
$address_index_no = 5;
$primary_contact_index_no = 7;
$new_export_records[] = $old_csv[0];

foreach($new_csv as $key=>$value){

    foreach($old_csv as $key1=>$value1){

        if( $old_csv[$key1][$state_index_no] == $new_csv[$key][$state_index_no] &&
            $old_csv[$key1][$city_index_no] == $new_csv[$key][$city_index_no] &&
            $old_csv[$key1][$name_index_no] == $new_csv[$key][$name_index_no] ){

            if($old_csv[$key1][$primary_contact_index_no] != 
               $new_csv[$key][$primary_contact_index_no]){

                $new_export_records[] = $new_csv[$key];

            }

            unset($old_csv[$key1]);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What you consider as a reasonable performance for your needs? do you need the answer in split second? few/several seconds? in current solution you have run time complexity of O(n^2) which is not very good :)

Comment: Do you simply want to know if both files differ in at least one of those fields, or do you want to collect all relevant rows (e.g. to do something with it in the next step)?

Comment: @Michael , if it can be done in a split second that would be awesome. do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @Yoshi, if i say that only one value is different , then how can i compare fast and get the new CSV records that have different that specific value ( 'PRIMARY CONTACT'   see the above array ) ?

Comment: @again.. this is depends on your needs, you need to think about this like a database, you have two edges 1. fast query time 2. fast indexing(or read) time. so you need to read the files *and* show to output to user in realtime? or this is a 2 separate processes?

Comment: @Michael , so there are 2 CSV files , Old and New ,  lets say i need to compare if the 'primary_contact' ( see above array ) , is different in the New CSV record as compared to OLD CSV record and assume the other fields have same data in both CSVs , then save that record in a seperate array ( see above code  --> $new_export_records ) , then at the end i export it ( $new_export_records ) as a CSV file in my code.

Comment: @ShayanArif Would you mind adding some sample data (use `var_export`) to your question.

Comment: @Yoshi, check above array , i copied it from New CSV , but OLD CSV is also like that.  i just pasted 1st two records , but there are around 25k records in both CSVs

Comment: @ShayanArif I understand that that's sample data, but it's a pain to rewrite it to actual usable data (as I said, use `var_export`) and it only contains one row, so one would have to generate additional sample data just to test a potential answer. Maybe use pastebin (or similar) to show some 100 rows, simply to make writing an answer less work.

Comment: @Yoshi, here is the link for sample 100 New CSV and 100 Old CSV records.

https://pastebin.com/cnDSxCgS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael pointed out, your current solution runs `n * m` times. With each being 25k, this is simply too much. But if you run through your old data first, create an index, and then run through the new data and check against that index, you'll be done in `m + n` iterations.

An example would be:

```
$name_index_no            = 1;
$state_index_no           = 2;
$city_index_no            = 3;
$country_index_no         = 4;
$address_index_no         = 5;
$primary_contact_index_no = 7;

$genKey = function ($row, $glue = '|') use ($state_index_no, $city_index_no, $name_index_no) {
    return implode($glue, [
        $row[$state_index_no],
        $row[$city_index_no],
        $row[$name_index_no],
    ]);
};


// create an index using the old data
$t = microtime(true);
$index = [];
foreach ($old_csv as $row) {
    $index[$genKey($row)] = $row;
}

printf('index generation: %.5fs', microtime(true) - $t);

// collect changed/new entries
$t = microtime(true);
$changed = [];
$new = [];
foreach ($new_csv as $row) {
    $key = $genKey($row);

    // key doesn't exist => new entry
    if (!isset($index[$key])) {
        $new[] = $row;
    }

    // primary contact differs => changed entry
    elseif ($row[$primary_contact_index_no] !== $index[$key][$primary_contact_index_no]) {
        $changed[] = $row;
    }
}

printf('comparison: %.5fs', microtime(true) - $t);
print_r($changed);
print_r($new);
```

Comment: i tried your code , but it gives only 9 records $changed array,  but there are 2k+ records that are different , which i got from my nested loops that runs about  3 minutes on my core i7 machine and takes about  6 minutes on my VPS hosting

Comment: Is it possible that there are duplicates for the checked fields (state, city, name)?

Comment: i remove the duplicates before also , see my updated above answer

Comment: I changed the code to use a string key (concatenation of the required fields), please try with the updated code.

Comment: thanks , it worked , you are awesome. I upvoted your answer but my reputation here is not high enough for it to show publicly here.

Comment: You're welcome! If you don't mind, please mark it as your accepted answer, so that it's visible to others.

Comment: i just wanted to share my speed results. Before with my slow algorithm it was taking  3 minutes on my laptop core i7 machine ,  and on my VPS hosting , it took 6 minutes.  But now with your code , on my local machine it took only 3 seconds , but on my VPS , it took 2 minutes and 30 seconds. Do you have any idea why would it be slow on my VPS ? is it related to the CPU cores and threads etc ?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but 2+ mins is quite strange, I wouldn't expect this code to run any slower than a few seconds even on weak machines. A thing could be the php version, you might want to check which is running on your vps and which one you're using on your laptop.

Comment: on my VPS (PHP Version 5.6.31) , on my local machine i have windows and using XAMPP ( PHP Version 5.6.30 )

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell. You might want to log different timings instead of the whole script. Try using [`microtime(true);`](https://php.net/manual/function.microtime.php) to check how long which part of the script takes. (I added it to the code in the answer.)

Comment: on my laptop:

index generation: 0.04300s
comparison: 0.05400s

on VPS:

index generation: 0.30116s
comparison: 0.37363s

So i assume your code is fast ,  maybe the slow is my previous code to remove the duplicates from both arrays.

Comment: duplication removal: 0.50063s , now i have no idea where the VPS is performing slow

Comment: Might be some side effect or other process. Usually connecting to a database can be very slow!?

Comment: I think i found the issue , basically my internet uploading speed is slow ( i was uploading CSV's ),  because i just timed the first line of code and exit after first line ,  but it took some time. but the time result was fast.